# Grep and split in unix

Tags: unix

I need to first grep the exact line and then to capture the required value.

eg.

```
Total logical records skipped:        0
Total logical records read:           500
Total logical records rejected:       3
Total logical records discarded:      0
```

I need to capture the value 500. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '/Total logical records read:/ { print $NF }' file.txt
```

If by capture, you mean store as a shell variable:

```
variable=$(awk '/Total logical records read:/ { print $NF }' file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep + awk:

```
cat log.txt | grep read | awk '{print $ 5;}'
```

or just awk:

```
cat log.txt | awk '/read/ {print $5;}'
```

Look at these examples: [Awk Introduction Tutorial – 7 Awk Print Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/)